# Could you spell it out for | to me

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is there any difference between:

Could you spell it out for me

vs

Could you spell it out to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference to the two words. However, the overall effect in the two sentences is the same.

To do something **for** someone is to do it on their behalf, at their request, or for their benefit.

To do something **to** someone is to do it with them as an object, essentially. To act *upon* them.

If you were asking someone to demonstrate a judo throw, then asking them to do it *for* you would mean they could do it with someone else, so you can see it. Asking them to do it *to* you would mean they demonstrate it with you as the one being thrown, so you can (for instance) feel what it is like to be thrown in that way.

In this case, to spell it for you necessitates spelling it to you, so the effect is the same. That's not to say there's no nuance between them; with the right tone and emphasis, there could be significant extra meaning to *for* over *to*, the idea that they are doing you a favour or they should do it because it's *you* that's asking. However, the practical meaning is the same, and that nuance would depend on tone at least as much as on the choice of words.

Comment: Does it depend on the meaning of "spell it out" (to explain in a very clear way with details or to say or write the letters of a word in the correct order)? Or "spell out" may also mean "spell aloud?"

Comment: Whether you mean "spell it out" literally or figuratively, the difference (or lack thereof) between *from* and *to* would be the same. That's not to say there would never be any nuance between the two, but the nuance would also not depend on the sense of "spell it out".